# Application-Defined or Object-defined error - Qualifying References Excel

Tags: vba, excel

Trying to hammer out bugs in my code. Currently trying to do some very simple, open worksheet, copy and paste data over. Trying to do it all without using .Select or .Activate. Hitting "Application-defined or Object defined error", which, from reading the other threads on the matter, probably means that my statements aren't fully qualified. However, I can't figure out how they're not fully qualified - other posts on the topic seem to be missing a "." somewhere in the code, but my attempts to fix it haven't gotten anywhere. Heavily truncated code as follows (If you don't see it dimmed/defined, it's elsewhere)

```
Sub CopyPaste()
Dim CitiReportEUR As Workbook
Dim CitiReportPathEUR  As String

CitiReportPathEUR = Range("CitiReportPathEUR")
  Workbooks.Open Filename:=CitiReportPathEUR
         Set CitiReportEUR = ActiveWorkbook

         LastRowCiti = CitiReportEUR.Sheets(1).Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
         Set RngCitiEUR = CitiReportEUR.Sheets(1).Range("A1:CT" & LastRowCiti).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

 Set CabReport.Sheets("CITI").Range("C1").Resize(RngCitiEUR.Rows.Count).Value = RngCitiEUR.Value
End Sub
```

Currently the error is occurring when I define the range. I've had problems historically with pasting into the range as well... but that's an issue for when I can actually get the code to run that far!

Comment: What is "LastRowCS" - where and how is it defined, what is its value? It is usually a good idea to make your code example "the smallest complete example that shows the problem". The code you show cannot be run without multiple errors. Can you create a piece of code we could copy to our computer and run - and get the same error? See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Am I right in thinking that your error went away when you fixed the typo (changing `LastRowCS` to `LastRowCiti`)?

Comment: `Rows.Count` hasn't been qualified, but the error will be coming from the inappropriate use of `Set` in the second-last line of your code.  Remove the `Set` (and qualify `Rows.Count`) and you should be OK.

Comment: And you may need to resize the columns as well as the rows, unless your source range will only be one column of the `A:CT` that you have used in setting `RngCitiEUR`.  (Not sure what your data is like, so can't be too sure.)

Comment: Ah, no, I also need to resize the columns, you're correct.

Answer (score 2):

1. `Rows.Count` is implicitly working with the ActiveSheet.
2. The use of `Set` when assigning values to the `Value` property of a `Range` is inappropriate.  `Set` should only be used when assigning a reference to an object.
3. The `Resize` probably needs to cater for the number of columns in the source as well as rows.

This code is more explicit:

```
Sub CopyPaste()
    Dim CitiReportEUR As Workbook
    Dim CitiReportPathEUR  As String

    CitiReportPathEUR = Range("CitiReportPathEUR")
    Set CitiReportEUR = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=CitiReportPathEUR)
    With CitiReportEUR.Sheets(1)
        LastRowCiti = .Range("I" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set RngCitiEUR = .Range("A1:CT" & LastRowCiti).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    End With   
    CabReport.Sheets("CITI").Range("C1").Resize(RngCitiEUR.Rows.Count, RngCitiEUR.Columns.Count).Value = RngCitiEUR.Value
End Sub
```